# How to access a struct from a class?

Tags: c++

I was reading a block of codes from a C++ book, and trying to compile it using g++

Here was the error:
main.cpp:11:3: error: ‘link’ does not name a type
main.cpp: In constructor ‘linklist::linklist()’:
main.cpp:15:4: error: ‘first’ was not declared in this scope

So it seems like the linklist class doesnt recognize the link struct, why?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct link //one element of list
{
    int data; //data item
    link* next; //pointer to next link
};
class linklist //a list of links
{
    private:
        link* first; //pointer to first link   !!!!!!!!Here is the first error ~!!!!!!!!!!!
    public:
        linklist() //no-argument constructor
        {
            first = NULL;
        } //no first link
        void additem(int d); //add data item (one link)
        void display(); //display all links
};
void linklist::additem(int d) //add data item
{
    link* newlink = new link; //make a new link
    newlink->data = d; //give it data
    newlink->next = first; //it points to next link
    first = newlink; //now first points to this
}
void linklist::display() //display all links
{
    link* current = first; //set ptr to first link
    while( current != NULL ) //quit on last link
    {
    cout << current->data << endl; //print data
    current = current->next; //move to next link
    }
}
int main()
{
        linklist li; //make linked list
        li.additem(25); //add four items to list
        li.additem(36);
        li.additem(49);
        li.additem(64);
        li.display(); //display entire list
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work for me, are you building it as C code?

Comment: I did use g++ <g++ main.cpp -o main> , and I ran it using <./main>

Comment: This code appears to compile fine: http://ideone.com/1X6qpR.

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: Is this the exact code you're compiling? The line that mentions `link` is line 13, not 14.

Comment: Sorry, some mistake, please see the update

Comment: Show us the command line you are using to build this code.

Comment: vim main.cpp
g++ main.cpp -o main
./main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the name link is conflict with a function named link in unistd.h. Try with g++ on the OS X.

Comment: No, there's no need for that weirdness in C++. (And personally I wouldn't recommend it in C either, though others may disagree).

Comment: This is only needed for C code. And a C compiler will not compile `class` definitions.

Comment: In fact, don't do it in C code either; `typedef struct link { ... } link;` is perfectly fine, and avoids weird underscore names.

Comment: To avoid such type of conflicts don't include std namespace in global. There are a lot of pitfalls which are very hard to detect and correct. One more example is a std::max and std::min functions.

Comment: @Boris Completely agree but for this particular case removing `using namespace std;` does not look like it fixes the issue.

Comment: @Boris: But in this case, the clash is apparently with `<unistd.h>`, which is a C header, and thus not in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are probably building this as C code, if I build using `g++` it works just fine but if I use `gcc` the first error is:

```
error: 'link' does not name a type
```

**Edit**

So I can reproduce this on `g++` by adding:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

So it looks like the name `link` conflicts with something in that header file. Renaming `link` to another name seems to fix the issue.

Comment: :(, I did use g++ <g++ main.cpp -o main> , and I ran it using <./main>

Comment: If you compile this as C, a bigger issue is `<iostream>` and `using namespace std` and `class`...

Comment: @user1701840 It is actually what PalmRobotZ said, I got a conflicting name with a symbol on unistd.h too.

Comment: @user1701840 I am able to reproduce that issue as well, I updated my answer.